# Обрезается фон при масштабировании

Tags: css

При масштабировании страницы, появляются странные отступы от краев браузера при 100% ширине:
Вот так выглядит при 100% обзоре в браузере, то есть все в порядке:
http://clip2net.com/s/3MfJYKn
Но стоит увеличить масштаб страницы хотя бы до 125% то почему-то обрезается слева вот так:
http://clip2net.com/s/3MfJSTT
Использую normalize.css, ширина основного контейнера 1170px. Как решить проблему?

```
   <div class="b-scheme">
    </div>

    .b-scheme {
        background: #f8f3f4;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
```

Comment: добавте пожалуйста код css и html, потому что так сложно сказать в чем проблема, но возможно просто нужно добавить background-size: cover; и всё

Comment: Обновил вопрос  1

Comment: у вас этот лемент у враппере и если да то у враппера эсть overflow: hidden?

Comment: лутше сделайте беграунд для елемента вне враппера, и тогда бегранд будет на всю шинину девайса